# form file upload phonegap

Tags: forms, cordova, file-upload

Please could someone upload a very basic but working version of a file upload script written in javascript that will then be phonegap friendly

I've trawled the internet trying to figure it out but most of the stuff out there is either out of date or the newer stuff seems to presume that you know all about the inner workings of phonegap

I grasp how to transfer the file but I cannot figure out how to explore/access the phones/tablets file system to look for the desired file for upload

In a perfect world phonegap would recognise the form file upload button and convert it so it works the same as if it were in a web browser but all it seems to do is disable it.

I'm using php as the sever side. I've spend days trying to understand how to do it... any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following. Get the file first and pass the file path and type as parameters.

```
function gotFile(file) {
    uploadFile(file.fullPath,file.type);
}

function uploadFile(imageURI,type) {

   var options = new FileUploadOptions();
   options.fileKey = "file";
   options.fileName = imageURI;
   options.mimeType = type;
   var params = {};
   //params.filePath = "files/";
   options.params = params;

   var ft = new FileTransfer();
   ft.upload(imageURI, "http:/www.xx.com/fileUpload.php",function onFileTransferSuccess(e){
       alert("File  Success");  

   }, fail, options);
}
```

your PHP server side function is like(fileUpload.php):

```
<?php
$new_image_name = "file.pdf";


$type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
//$paramValue = $_POST['value1'];


move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "your storage location".$new_image_name);
?>
```

let me know any difficulties.

Comment: Hello Aravin, Thanks for your reply. The issue I was having was that of accessing the file explorer on the phone/tablet (namely android) so even though the code you kindly supplied uploads the file I was still having issues accessing the the file....HOWEVER! I just ran an update on my nexus 5 and now the file upload button is working, very odd and frustrating as the issue has been resolved but I'm none the wiser how, not sure if it was something I was doing wrong or an issue with android. Thanks again for answering the question, I'll update this question when I know what the issue was