# Phonegap/Cordova upload image file

Tags: image, file, cordova, file-upload

In an external website have an input (type - file) field and I need to upload an image to this input.
In android I made this task with WebChromeClient and with openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) function.
I have no idea how to solve this task in phonegap / cordova.

My code is:

```
function initialize() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    var ref = null;
}
function onDeviceReady() {

    ref = window.open('http://example.com',
            '_blank', 'location=no', 'EnableViewPortScale=yes');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);

}

function LoadStop(event) {
    if (event.url == 'http://example.com/Add') {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
            alert('get picture failed');
        }, {
            quality : 50,
            destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        });
    }
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    console.log("imageURI----: " + imageURI);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = "IMAG0475";
    options.mimeType = "image/*";

    var params = new Object();
    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI,
            encodeURI("http://example/Add"), win,
            fail, options);

}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139295/form-file-upload-phonegap/24142596#24142596

Answer (score 0):

By default cordova applications do not have access to all storage locations in an Android phone for example, sdcard, external-files.

To resolve this, copy the following line to the config.xml of your cordova project,

```js
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root"/>
```

Config.xml can be found at /platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

Just add the above line and build the project once again.