# Phonegap upload image with caption and retrieve them

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, cordova

i need to upload image from android or iphone with a little bit of description or caption to remote server  using phone gap file api but am not familiar with php can any one help me to solve this problem give ma bit of code because i need it badly

Comment: check this for file transfer in phonegap using phonegap..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139295/form-file-upload-phonegap/24142596#24142596

Comment: i already done image upload using phonegap but the problem is  i need to upload caption or descrition also for each image

Comment: you can use `options.params = params;` to pass description...

Comment: ok then how i save it on database and retrieve them ?

Comment: what you want to save it in database?

Comment: a desction tex or caption or both of them

Comment: how you are capture the description?. In phonegap use sqlite to store.

Comment: no no localdb or sql i want to store it in server and retrieve them, first i take the pgoto then the photo will appear in phonegap appa then below there is field for caption and write caption the click post then the photo and caption will save in server

Comment: Assign the caption to param like `options.params = params;` then get in the PHP like $caption = $_FILES["file"]["param"];

Comment: am not familiar with php ,can u give me an example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like in your phonegap app:

```
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI;
    options.mimeType = type;

    var params = new Object();
    params.caption = "test";
    params.value1 = "param";

    options.params = params;


var ft = new FileTransfer();
   ft.upload(imageURI, "http:/url/fileUpload.php",function onFileTransferSuccess(e){
       alert("File  Success");  

   }, fail, options);
```

then in your PHP code like(fileUpload.php):

```
<?php
   $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
   $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   // here you can get your caption value passed from phonegap File transfer.
   $caption =  $_POST["caption"]
?>
```